# Why and when do we use digit '9' before making an outbound call?

Tags: voip, voice

Also explain when do we use this feature (Please explain for both VOIP & Traditional telephony system)? Why we use this feature? what problems shall we face if we don't use '9' before making outbound call? explain this in reference to North American Numbering Plan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In traditional **public** telephony in USA exists the North American Numbering Plan that defines this:

- **NPA**  (Numbering plan Area Code) 3 digits
- **NXX**  (Central Office) 3 digits
- **xxxx** (Subscriber Number) 4 digits

If you call whitin the same area code you don't need to dial it, so you can dial NXX-xxxx (*7 digits*)

If you call to another area code you need to dial it, so you have to dial NPA-NXX-xxxx (*10 digits*).

If you need to call to a foreign country you have to use the **international prefix**: *011* (for example: 011 + country code + number).

In addition, the [NANPA defines N11 codes](https://www.nationalnanpa.com/number_resource_info/n11_codes.html):

- 211  Community Information and Referral Services
- 311  Non-Emergency Police and Other Governmental Services
- 411  Local Directory Assistance
- 511  Traffic and Transportation Information (US); Provision of Weather
  and Traveller Information Services (Canada)
- 611  Repair Service
- 711  Telecommunications Relay Service (TRS)
- 811  Access to One Call Services to Protect Pipeline and Utilities
  from Excavation Damage (US); Non-Urgent Health Teletriage Services
  (Canada)
- 911  Emergency

---

The administrator of a **private PBX** has a group of internal extensions with their own numeration. For example *[300-399 accounting]*, *[400-499 sales]*, *[800-899 management]*, etc.

To determine easily if an user is dialing to another extension or to an outside number a group of rules can be set in this way:

- User dials a number beginning with a number between 2 and 8 -> Internal call (connect directly to the number dialed).
- Dial a number beginning with 9 -> External (ditch the '9' and send the rest of the numbers to the local telco).

0 seems to be a good choice, however can be confusing because the **international prefix**

9 is a good choice. The only restrictions are:

- None of the extensions can begin with 9.
- There is not direct dialing of *911*, people will need to dial *9911*.

---

Modern PBXs can be set using rules by number length, so the rules can be modified to:

- Dial 911 -> Emergency Call -> Send the call
- Dial a number beginning with 9 plus more than 2 digits -> External (ditch the '9' and send the rest of the numbers to the local telco).

  In that way, both numbers work (911 and 9911).

Comment: you're saying the digit '9' will be ditched & rest of the numbers will be out plused but what if I'm dialing emergency call '911'?? Do I need to dial '911' or '9911'?

Comment: @Heisenberg I added an explanation about it on the answer.

Comment: See Also: "Dial Plan" Modern systems can match and rewrite anything dialed, so "9+number" is usually only included as a fallback. For example, my (cisco) setup has rules for selecting a specific outside line (*30, *31, ...) There used to also be "8+number" for making "long distance" calls, to select different call routing.

Comment: In the US, most modern PBX system will have a rule to handle "9-1-1" (in some places, it's required by law.)